Volume of cone part cone
I am breaking my head over this, I just want to be sure.
Volume of cone is given as
$$
V = \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 H
$$
Now lets say I need volume of this cone but not all the way to height h but say to some height h.
How would I find it? Is it simply
$$
V =
\int_{0}^{H} \pi \left(\frac{r}{H}\,z\right)^2 \, dz
$$.
Do I just integrate it to my height h? And does it matter that top of cone won't be pointy?

A way to check your work: you know the volume must be a little cone subtracted from a bigger cone.

A quick look suggests that formula is wrong. What you might want to do is say to yourself "if I slice the cone at some height z, what radius does the resulting disk have"? That's the thing you need to integrate. And that radius will depend on TWO numbers: the radius $r_1$ of the bottom disk of your truncated cone and the radius of the top disk $r_2$. Your overall answer should involve $r_1, r_2,$ and $H$ (the height of the truncated cone). To check your radius-of-slice formula, plug in $z = 0$ (you should get $r_1$) and $z = H$ (you should get $r_2$).

I think that in your question, you've conflated $h$ and $H$ at various points. It'd be worth sorting that out, because "not all the way to height $h$, but say to some height $h$" doesn't really make sense.
